# C# simple linq with enum

Tags: c#, linq

I got a enum like this:

```
public enum PlatForms
{
    AAA=1,
    BBB=2,
    CCC=3
}
```

and a function like this:

```
public List<Something> GetSomething(PlatForms pf)
{
    switch(pf)
    {
        case PlatForms.AAA:
            var some = context.table1.Where(x => x.Prop == true);
            break;
        case PlatForms.BBB:
            var some2 = context.table2.Where(x => x.Prop == true);
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    //do convert;
    //
}
```

The difference is table name is not same. How do I rewrite the code to make it simple?

Comment: Use `DbContext.Set<T>()` and pass in the generic type to your method.

Comment: What is `Something`, i.e. how do you get `some` or `some2` to end up as the same type `Something`

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

You wouldn't want this Dictionary code to run every single time, so as soon as you have your context you could initialize a Dictionary...

```
        var tableTranslation = new Dictionary<Platforms, Context>();
        tableTranslation.Add(Platforms.AAA, context.table1);
        tableTranslation.Add(Platforms.BBB, context.table2);
```

Then in your GetSomething() method you could just reference the Dictionary's table.

```
        var some = tableTranslation[pf].Where(x => x.Prop == true);
        //do convert
```

Would that do what you're looking for?